# Is it can be bad to fetch html file instead of fetch json and create html and why?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

[shop window with pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olJVo.jpg)

I must implement working pagination with changing content in store window (on this screenshot above).
I can't choose between fetch html file with these products or it will be better to fetch JSON with data about products and create html elements and append them to store window container. Can't find any info about, help)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm afraid your question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow as it is extremely broad, opinion based and it looks like you're asking for a tutorial over the pros and cons.

The truth is, either method works -- they each have pros and cons. Both your front-end and back-end setup play into it.

Comment: Thanks for welcome, but I ask why is it can be bad to fetch html and append it to dom elements,not even pros and cons or anything else!

Answer (score 1):

It's better to fetch JSON and then extract data from it and append to your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Searching all day but only now find out this:

> It may be tempting to fetch HTML and append that using the innerHTML attribute, but be careful -- this can expose your site to cross site scripting attacks!
>   https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api

Comment: This is true if you don't have full control over the HTML you're retrieving via fetch, i.e. if the html contains content created by the users or if it's from an external source that you're not managing yourself

Answer (score 0):

If the content is changing,it is much easier to work with JSON and then create HTML element to show the windows.HTML is not a programming language and if you want to fetch contents with HTML you must create a tag for every element

Answer (score 0):

HTML by nature is static, while your data is most likely dynamic.
So first take the following into consideration:

- how will adding/removing a few products affect the pages? - think of inserting an item on the first page, you'll need to push all the rest of the items back one position
- do you want to copy/paste the same HTML structure for every new page of products?
- if you want to change the HTML structure of your design, are you willing to modify every single .html file? (you could have dozens, maybe thousands of them)
- are you planning on implementing sorting or filtering of the products?

I think that most of the above points will lead to realising that you need to build a dynamic application which renders JSON data into an HTML template, if you value your sanity and your time. You can keep it basic and write a couple of jQuery scripts that load the data and generate HTML on the fly, but those tend to become fiddly and hard to maintain. IMO it would be best to invest some time in learning a modern framework such as Vue, React or Angular, these will make your life a lot easier on the long run.

However, if you only need to build a dummy prototype where you need to showcase how the store is supposed to look and behave like, then by all means go down the HTML route - just make sure no one expects you to maintain that list of products :)